# expo dev client application doesn't open

Tags: expo, react-native

I'm trying to use expo-dev-client to add react-native-sms-retriever library to my project because expo doesn't have a library that supports reading sms messages. In expo documentation, it's suggested that I should use expo-dev-client to add custom native code. You can see the documentation here: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/customizing/#developing-apps-with-custom-native-code

I followed all of the steps in starting guide for expo-dev-client.   https://docs.expo.dev/clients/getting-started/

But when I start my app using "expo start --dev-client" and run on android, a white screen is shown for a second and then I'm redirected to expo go application page.
in console, the following 2 lines are written:

```
› Opening on Android...

› Opening com.droppgroup.masterclean://expo-development-client/?url=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8081 on LDN_L21
```

I tried this on real device and 2 other emulators but I got the same result. I reinstalled expo go application and it still doesn't work.
Any suggestions on what I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

The issue may be a problem with Expo [config plugins](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/), which configure native code for an Expo project, by configuring Info.plist for example. I am currently experiencing a similar issue, though after scanning the QR code, I am directed to a black screen in my Expo Dev Client which crashes and takes me back to the home page. The Dev Client worked perfected until I ran `expo add react-native-bluetooth-classic`, since I am trying to access iOS bluetooth APIs. I am currently working on this issue, but I just wanted to point you in the direction of config plugins since the examples Expo gives for customizing your runtime have config plugins registred in the "plugins" property of app.json.

It may be necessary to create your own plugin, though I am unsure.

Please let me know if you come up with any fixes, and so will I.

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer?